# Create API key for YouTube channel, where I am not owner

Tags: youtube-api

I do have a Google account. I was invited in other YouTube channel with Manager role.
Is it possible to create an API key for working with this channel without being its owner.
The goal is to upload videos on that YouTube channel without having the owner's credentials.

Comment: welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  API keys are only for reading public data they can not read private user data for that you need Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. Okay. I can use Oath 2.0 with Secrete Key and Client Id.And my question stays same.

Comment: The owner of the channel or someone with access to the channel is going to have to run your application which identifies itself by the client id and secret key.    They can then grant your application access to their data.   This is not something that you can do behind the seens they must run your application.   You cant access someones account with out their permission.   You can not do this with their login and password either.  You must authorize though Oauth2 and request permisson.